# What can I know about data if I know where they are, e.g. 0xffffffff7fffd9d8 vs. 0x10019c1e0?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am wondering if the numeric value of a pointer tells me something of use during debugging.

For example I have the following on my call stack:

```
std::basic_ostringstream<char, std, char_traits<char>, std::allocator, <char>void>::str(
    0xffffffff7fffd9d8, 
    0x10019c1e0, 
    0x100446710, 
    0x0, 
    0xffffffff7fffd9d8, 
    0xffffffff7b331688), 
at 0xffffffff7b1b28ec
```

There seem to be pointers of the form `0xfff` and `0x100`. Is there a meaning to this difference?

Comment: _"Is there a meaning to this difference?"_ Well, define meaning better. Which  _meaning_ besides seeing very different memory address ranges do you want to imply?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There must be some reason they are stored in different memory regions. Is one ob both in the heap perhaps? By meaning I mean a reson that explains the obvious dissimilarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 64-bit platforms, in theory you could address 2<sup>64</sup> or approximately 16 exabytes. Since most applications don’t need such a large address space, hardware vendors define smaller virtual address spaces to reduce the cost of address translation. Therefore, on AMD and Intel chips, only the least significant 48 bits of the address are significant, and bits 48 through 63 must be copies of bit 47. These are called *canonical form* addresses, and they span the following ranges:

- `0000000000000000` — `00007FFFFFFFFFFF`
- `FFFF800000000000` — `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

The former are called *canonical lower half* addresses, and the latter *canonical upper half*. It’s the decision of the kernel, but *typically* upper-half addresses refer to the stack and static program data area, while lower-half addresses refer to heap memory.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint you should take with a grain of salt. On 64-bit x86 Linux stack addresses generally are in the upper range, while the heap addresses are in the lower range. So your `0xffff` form addresses are probably from the stack, and `0x100` from the heap.